# How could I use dbRepository in my websocketConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to use my tokenRepository in my `WebSocketConfig` which implements `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

In my controller I could get the `tokenRepository` by `@Autowired, but`websocketConfig` couldn't

I override `configureClientInboundChannel` in `WebSocketConfig` to get data when user connect web socket

In `WebSocketConfig`

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    logger.debug(">>>[CONFIG CLIENT INBOUND CHANNEL]");
    registration.interceptors(new SelfChannelInterceptor());
}
```

In `SelfChannelInterceptor`

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
    if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
        String token = accessor.getNativeHeader("token").get(0);
        String id = accessor.getNativeHeader("id").get(0);
        if (!validConnection(token, id)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No permission to this connection");
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

the token data saved in DB for validation.

But how could I let `WebSocketConfig` get the `tokenRepository`

Example in `tokenController` to check db

```
private JwtRepository jwtRepository;

private TokenService tokenService;

@Autowired
public TokenController(TokenRepository tokenRepository){

    jwtRepository = new JwtRepository("xxxxxxx", "yyyyyyy");

    tokenService = new TokenService(tokenRepository);

}

@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Token> getAll(){

    List<Token> tokens = tokenService.getAllTokens();

    return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I found a way to solve this problem.

I use CompletableFuture to let `SelfChannelInterceptor` gets what I `@Autowired` in the `WebSocketConfig`

In `WebSocketConfig`

```
private CompletableFuture<ServiceImpFactory> completableFutureService = new CompletableFuture<>();

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    completableFutureService.complete(this.serviceImpFactory);
}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    logger.debug(">>>[CONFIG CLIENT INBOUND CHANNEL]");
    registration.interceptors(new SelfChannelInterceptor(completableFutureService));
}
```

In `SelfChannelInterceptor` I could use `CompletableFuture.get()` to get what I want pass to

`SelfChannelInterceptor`

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

    ServiceFactory serviceFactory = serviceImpFactoryCompletableFuture.get();

    return message;
}
```

I thought that the websocketConfig may add some `aspect` to call the method in this class.
So the method `configureClientInboundChannel` would run at the first time. But how to add AOP on `interface`? Cause I implement `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

I will keep search if there got any way to remove `aspect` or do it later.